# Find an unknown string between two known characters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to be able to extract  the three strings separated by a dashes "-" from an input string.
For example:

```
Mystring="54-0-9";
```

the values separated by "-" are with unknown length because they should be an input for the user.

The user should enter each value in a textField than my code concatenate the 3 values and put it as shown . Later i want to get the three values separated again each one in a new text field. How can i do that in c# !?

Comment: Using string.Split seems to be the right path

Comment: is the user allowed to put a dash in the string?

Comment: no he just need to enter the three values between dashes than my code should concatenate the three inputs and put between them "-" just to look as three separated values and make easy searching for them separated later as my question is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [string split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx).

```
// Select on "-".
string[] split = _string.Split(new Char[] { '-' });
```

`split[0]`, `split[1]`, `split[2]` will have the values you want.

Comment: thanks seems to be  an easy way .

Answer (score 3):

```
Mystring="54-0-9";
Mystring.Split('-');
```

this will give you a array of 3 now.